# splitting strings by list of separators irrespective of order

Tags: python, string, list, separator

I have a *string* `text` and a *list* `names`

- I want to **split** `text` **every time an element of** `names` **occurs**.

`text = 'Monika goes shopping. Then she rides bike. Mike likes Pizza. Monika hates me.'`

`names = ['Mike', 'Monika']`

**desired output:**

`output = [['Monika', ' goes shopping. Then she rides bike.'], ['Mike', ' likes Pizza.'], ['Monika', ' hates me.']]`

**FAQ**

- `text` does not always start with a `names` element. Thanks for VictorLee pointing that out. I dont care about that leading part but others maybe do, so thanks for the people answering "both cases"
- The order of the *separators* within `names` is independend of their occurance in `text`.
- *separators* within `names` are unique but can occur multiple times throughout `text`. Therefore the output will have more *lists* than `names` has *strings*.
- `text` will never have the same unique `names` element occuring twice consecutively/<>.
- Ultimately I want the output to be a *list of lists* where each split `text` slice corresponds to its *separator*, that it was split by. Order of lists doesent matter.

`re.split()` wont let me use a list as a separator argument. Can I `re.compile()` my separator list?

---

**update:** Thomas code works best for my case, but I noticed one caveat i havent realized before:

some of the elements of `names` are preceded by 'Mrs.' or 'Mr.' while only some of the corresponding matches in `text` are preceded by 'Mrs.' or 'Mr.'

---

so far:

```
names = ['Mr. Mike, ADS', 'Monika, TFO', 'Peter, WQR']
text1 = ['Mrs. Monika, TFO goes shopping. Then she rides bike. Mike, ADS likes Pizza. Monika, TFO hates me.']
text = str(text1)[1:-1]

def create_regex_string(name: List[str]) -> str:
    name_components = name.split()
    if len(name_components) == 1:
        return re.escape(name)
    salutation, *name = name_components
    return f"({re.escape(salutation)} )?{re.escape(' '.join(name))}"
    
regex_string = "|".join(create_regex_string(name) for name in names)
group_count = regex_string.count("(") + 1
fragments = re.split(f"({regex_string})", text)
if fragments:
    # ignoring text before first occurrence, not specified in requirements
    if not fragments[0] in names: 
        fragments = fragments[1:]
        result = [[name, clist.rstrip()] for name, clist in zip(
            fragments[::group_count+1],
            fragments[group_count::group_count+1]
        ) if clist is not None
    ]

print(result)
[['Monika, TFO', ' goes shopping. Then she rides bike.'], ['Mike, ADS', ' likes Pizza.'], ['Monika, TFO', " hates me.'"]]
```

error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [86], in <module>
    111     salutation, *name = name_components
    112     return f"({re.escape(salutation)} )?{re.escape(' '.join(name))}"
--> 114 regex_string = "|".join(create_regex_string(name) for name in mps)
    115 group_count = regex_string.count("(") + 1
    116 fragments = re.split(f"({regex_string})", clist)

Input In [86], in <genexpr>(.0)
    111     salutation, *name = name_components
    112     return f"({re.escape(salutation)} )?{re.escape(' '.join(name))}"
--> 114 regex_string = "|".join(create_regex_string(name) for name in mps)
    115 group_count = regex_string.count("(") + 1
    116 fragments = re.split(f"({regex_string})", clist)

Input In [86], in create_regex_string(name)
    109 if len(name_components) == 1:
    110     return re.escape(name)
--> 111 salutation, *name = name_components
    112 return f"({re.escape(salutation)} )?{re.escape(' '.join(name))}"

ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected at least 1, got 0)
```

Comment: Is the **text** must starts with the element in **names**?

Comment: Do you necessarily want to use re for this?

Comment: No, i dont care about performance. If others have a similar problem they may care?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for a way to use regular expressions, then:

```py
import re

def do_split(text, names):
    joined_names = '|'.join(re.escape(name) for name in names)

    regex1 = re.compile('(?=' + joined_names + ')')
    strings = filter(lambda s: s != '', regex1.split(text))

    regex2 = re.compile('(' + joined_names + ')')
    return [list(filter(lambda s: s != '', regex2.split(s.rstrip()))) for s in strings]

text = 'Monika goes shopping. Then she rides bike. Mike likes Pizza. Monika hates me.'
names = ['Mike', 'Monika']
print(do_split(text, names))
```

Prints:

```None
[['Monika', ' goes shopping. Then she rides bike.'], ['Mike', ' likes Pizza.'], ['Monika', ' hates me.']]
```

**Explanation**

First we dynamically create a regex `regex1` from the past *names* argument to be:

```
(?=Mike|Monika)
```

When you split the input on this you, because any of the passed names may appear at the beginning or end of the input, you could end up with empty strings in the result and so we will filter those out and get:

```
['Monika goes shopping. Then she rides bike. ', 'Mike likes Pizza. ', 'Monika hates me.']
```

Then we split each list on:

```
(Mike|Monika)
```

And again we filter out any possible empty strings to get our final result.

**The key to all of this is that when our regex on which we split contains a capture group, the text of that capture group is also returned as part of the resulting list.**

**Update**

You did not specify what should occur if the input text does not being with one of the names. On the assumption that you *might* want to ignore all of the string until you find one of the names, then check out the following version. Likewise, if the text does not contain any of the names, then the updated code will just return an empty list:

```py
import re

def do_split(text, names):
    joined_names = '|'.join(re.escape(name) for name in names)

    regex0 = re.compile('(' + joined_names + ')[\s\S]*')
    m = regex0.search(text)
    if not m:
        return []
    text = m.group(0)

    regex1 = re.compile('(?=' + joined_names + ')')
    strings = filter(lambda s: s != '', regex1.split(text))

    regex2 = re.compile('(' + joined_names + ')')
    return [list(filter(lambda s: s != '', regex2.split(s.rstrip()))) for s in strings]

text = 'I think Monika goes shopping. Then she rides bike. Mike likes Pizza. Monika hates me.'
names = ['Mike', 'Monika']
print(do_split(text, names))
```

Prints:

```None
[['Monika', ' goes shopping. Then she rides bike.'], ['Mike', ' likes Pizza.'], ['Monika', ' hates me.']]
```

Comment: It not work while **text** not start with the element in **names**.

Comment: @VictorLee  I have updated the answer to handle text that does not begin with a name. But, in fact, not only did the OP not specify what should happen in this case, you even asked what should happen and have not received a reply yet. So both of us are making an assumption as to what should be done. But I have left both answers because I am not sure that the first approach is not the correct one.

Comment: One more thing, the second element in sub list should format by `rstrip()`.

Answer (score 1):

Against with regular expressions, you also could reconstruct **text** to a suitable format which will get the expect result by `split` method. And add some string format process.

```
# works on python2 or python3, but the time complexity is O(n2) means n*n
def do_split(text, names):
    my_sprt = '|'
    tmp_text_arr = text.split()
    for i in range(len(tmp_text_arr)):
        for sprt in names:
            if sprt == tmp_text_arr[i]:
                tmp_text_arr[i] = my_sprt + sprt + my_sprt

    tmp_text = ' '.join(tmp_text_arr)
    if tmp_text.startswith(my_sprt):
        tmp_text = tmp_text[1:]

    tmp_text_arr = tmp_text.split(my_sprt)
    if tmp_text_arr[0] not in names:
        tmp_text_arr.pop(0)

    out_arr = []
    for i in range(0, len(tmp_text_arr) - 1, 2):
        out_arr.append([tmp_text_arr[i], tmp_text_arr[i + 1].rstrip()])
    return out_arr

text = 'Monika goes shopping. Then she rides bike. Mike likes Pizza. Monika hates me.'
text = 'today Monika goes shopping. Then she rides bike. Mike likes Pizza. Monika hates me.'
names = ['Mike', 'Monika']
print(do_split(text, names))
```

This code will **compatible** with **text** which not start with the element in **names**.

Key point: reformat **text** value to `|Monika| goes shopping. Then she rides bike. |Mike| likes Pizza. |Monika| hates me.` with self-define separator such as `|` which should not occur in original **text**.

Comment: `xrange` is a Python2-only function yet you are executing `print` with parentheses as if it were a Python3-style `print` function call, which with Python2 means you are passing either a parenthesized expression or a tuple to be printed depending on the number of commas within the parentheses. It's a bit strange. It's like you were converting a Python2 program to Python3 but forgot about `xrange`.

Comment: Obviously, I run it by `python2`, it also works with `print()`. While run by `python3`, need to change `xrange` to `range`.

Comment: My point is that if you have multiple items within the parentheses with `print`, for example `print(1, 2)`, then instead of printing `1 2`, you end up printing `(1, 2)`.

Comment: Oh, I see. I just don't change the code which copy from yours, bcz it works in this situation.

Comment: @Booboo thanks for your tips, I update `xrange` to `range` for compatible with `python2` and `python3`. I just consider that `xrange` better than `range` in `python2` before.

Comment: Then keep `xrange` but either use the standard Python2 `print` statement syntax (without the parentheses) or add as the *first* line of your code `from __future__ import print_function`.

Comment: OK, I keep that bcz of simple and compatible.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244035/discussion-between-victorlee-and-booboo).

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`re.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split) along with [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

```py
import re
from pprint import pprint

text = "Monika goes shopping. Then she rides bike. Mike likes Pizza." \
       "Monika hates me."

names = ["Henry", "Mike", "Monika"]

regex_string = "|".join(re.escape(name) for name in names)

fragments = re.split(f"({regex_string})", text)

if fragments:

    # ignoring text before first occurrence, not specified in requirements
    if not fragments[0] in names: 
        fragments = fragments[1:]

    result = [
        [name, text.rstrip()] 
        for name, text in zip(fragments[::2], fragments[1::2])
    ]

    pprint(result)
```

**Output:**

```py
[['Monika', ' goes shopping. Then she rides bike.'],
 ['Mike', ' likes Pizza.'],
 ['Monika', ' hates me.']]
```

**Notes:**

- This is an answer for question [revision 9](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/71855056/9).

  - There is an update at the very end of this answer considering the changes in question [revision 11](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/71855056/11).
- You don't specify if "text" before the first occurrence of a name should be considered or not.

  - Script above ignores "text" before the first occurrence.
- You also don't specify what happens if the text ends with a name.

  - Script above will include the occurrence by adding an empty string. However, can be easily be solved by removing the last element if the "text" is an empty string.
- `zip` works because there is always an even number of elements in `fragments`. We remove the first element if it does not match a name (either text or empty string), and the last element is always an empty string if the text ends with a name.

According to [`re.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split):

> If there are capturing groups in the separator and it matches at the start of the string, the result will start with an empty string. The same holds for the end of the string [...]

---

Here is the same example but not ignoring "text" before the first occurrence:

```py
import re

text = "Hi. Monika goes shopping. Then she rides bike. Mike likes Pizza." \
       "Monika hates me."

names = ["Henry", "Mike", "Monika"]

regex_string = "|".join(re.escape(name) for name in names)

fragments = re.split(f"({regex_string})", text)

if fragments:

    # not ignoring text before first occurrence; use empty string as name
    if fragments[0].strip() == "":
        fragments = fragments[1:]
    elif not fragments[0] in names:
        fragments = [""] + fragments

    result = [
        [name, text.rstrip()]
        for name, text in zip(fragments[::2], fragments[1::2])
    ]

    # # remove empty text
    # if result and not result[-1][1]:
    #     result = result[:-1]

    print(result)  # [['', 'Hi.'], ['Monika', ...] ..., ['Monika', ' hates me.']]
```

**Notes:**

- This is an answer for question [revision 9](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/71855056/9).

  - There is an update at the very end of this answer considering the changes in question [revision 11](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/71855056/11).

---

#### Update for Question [Revision 11](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/71855056/11)

Following an attempt to include id345678 additional requirement:

```py
import re
from pprint import pprint
from typing import List
```

```py
def create_regex_string(name: List[str]) -> str:

    name_components = name.split()

    if len(name_components) == 1:
        return re.escape(name)

    salutation, name_part = name_components

    return f"({re.escape(salutation)} )?{re.escape(name_part)}"
```

```py
text = "Monika goes shopping. Then she rides bike. Dr. Mike likes Pizza. " \
       "Mrs. Monika hates me. Henry needs a break."

names = ["Henry", "Dr. Mike", "Mrs. Monika"]

regex_string = "|".join(create_regex_string(name) for name in names)

group_count = regex_string.count("(") + 1

fragments = re.split(f"({regex_string})", text)

if fragments:

    # ignoring text before first occurrence, not specified in requirements
    if not fragments[0] in names: 
        fragments = fragments[1:]

    result = [
        [name, text.rstrip()] 
        for name, text in zip(
            fragments[::group_count+1],
            fragments[group_count::group_count+1]
        )
    ]

    pprint(result)
```

**Output:**

```py
[['Monika', ' goes shopping. Then she rides bike.'],
 ['Dr. Mike', ' likes Pizza.'],
 ['Mrs. Monika', ' hates me.'],
 ['Henry', ' needs a break.']]
```

**Notes:**

- final regex string is then `(Henry|Mike|(Mrs\. )?Monika)`

  - eg. `create_regex_string("Mrs. Monika")` creates `(Mrs\. )?Monika`
  - it will also work for other salutations (as long as there is one space separating the salutation from the name)
- because we introduced an additional grouping in the regex, `fragments` has more values

  - therefore, we needed to change the line with `zip` so it is dynamically
- and if you don't want the salutation in the `result`, you can use `name.split()[-1]` when creating `result`:

```py
result = [
    [name.split()[-1], text.rstrip()] 
    for name, text in zip(
        fragments[::group_count+1],
        fragments[group_count::group_count+1]
    )
]

# [['Monika', ' goes shopping. Then she rides bike.'],
#  ['Mike', ' likes Pizza.'],
#  ['Monika', ' hates me.'],
#  ['Henry', ' needs a break.']]
```

**Please note:** I have not tested all use cases as I updated the script on my break time. Let me know if there are issues and then I will look into it when I am off work.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this! I updated my question. I would appreciate it very much if you could have a second look?

Comment: Thanks again, take your time :) `ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)` i added the full traceback to the question above.

Comment: Get the same error when having `"Dr. Mike Stuart"`. You can solve this with `salutation, *name = name_components` and `return f"({re.escape(salutation)} )?{re.escape(' '.join(name))}"`.

Comment: Note: `[name.split()[-1], text.rstrip()]` will not work after this change. However, it won't be to difficult to work around that. ;)

Comment: However, this will not work if you have `"Mike Stuart"`. You'll need to look into this too. You will have to check against some sort dictionary if first element after using `split()` is a salutation and handle it differently if not. Please put some effort in it to solve it yourself and if you are not able to please ask a new question.

Comment: Ok. thanks for the effort :) I revised a bit and am now stuck with the updated error above. My problem is that i dont fully understand your code. I cannot infer what the source of the new error `ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected at least 1, got 0)`. I added the traceback above. Thanks again for considering :)

Comment: You can [unpack lists and tuples](https://www.pythonmorsels.com/tuple-unpacking/). In your error, it says that there is no element in the tuple but it expect 1. I assume that the error happens here: `salutation, name = name_components`, and I assume that `len(name_components) == 0`.  The question is, why is `name_components` empty? `name` is probably an empty string. Hope that helps.

Comment: `names[:] = [x for x in names if x]` ensures there are no empty strings in that list, right?

Comment: Yes, `[x for x in names if x]` would remove the empty strings.

Answer (score 1):

I took one of your given solutions and slightly refactored it.

```
def split(txt, seps, actual_sep='\1'):
    order = [item for item in txt.split() if item in seps ]
    for sep in seps:
        txt = txt.replace(sep, actual_sep)
    return list( zip( order, [i.strip() for i in txt.split(actual_sep) if bool(i.strip())] ) )

text = 'Monika goes shopping. Then she rides bike. Mike likes Pizza. Monika hates me.'
names = ['Mike', 'Monika']

print( split(text, names) )
```

**EDITED**

Another solution to account for some edge case mentioned here.

```py
def split(txt, seps, sep_pack='\1'):
    for sep in seps:
        txt = txt.replace(sep, f"{sep_pack}{sep}{sep_pack}")
    
    lst = txt.split(sep_pack)
    temp = []
    idx = 0
    for _ in range(len(lst)):
        if idx < len(lst):
            if lst[idx] in seps:
                temp.append( [lst[idx], lst[idx+1]] )
                idx+=2
            else:
                temp.append( ['', lst[idx]] )
                idx+=1

    return temp
```

*Kinda ugly though, looking to improve.*

Comment: I would like to point out that using `re` would most likely result in more efficient code.

Answer (score 1):

This is in a similar vein to some answers here, but simpler.

There are three steps:

1. Find all occurrences of a separator
2. Split apart the remaining text
3. Combine the results from (1) and (2) into a list of lists, as desired

We can combine (1) and (2) but it makes creating the list of lists more complicated.

```
import re

def split_on_names(names: list[str], text: str) -> list[list[str]]:
    pattern = re.compile("|".join(map(re.escape, names)))
    # step 1: find the separators (in order)
    separator = pattern.findall(text)
    # step 2: split out the text between separators
    remainder = list(filter(None, pattern.split(text)))

    # at this point, if `remainder` is longer, it's because `text` 
    # didn't start with a separator. So, we add a blank separator
    # to account for the prefix.
    if len(remainder) > len(separator):
        separator = ["", *separator]

    # step 3: reshape the results into a list of lists
    return list(map(list, zip(separator, remainder)))
```

```
names = ["Mike", "Monika"]
text = "Hi Monika goes shopping. Then she rides bike. Mike likes Pizza. Monika hates me."

split_on_names(names, text)

# output:
#
# [
#    ['', 'Hi '],
#    ['Monika', ' goes shopping. Then she rides bike. '],
#    ['Mike', ' likes Pizza. '],
#    ['Monika', ' hates me.']
# ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your example doesn't fully match your desired output. Also, it's not clear is the example input will *always* have this structure e.g. with the period at the end of each sentence.

Having said that, you might want to try this dirty approach:

```py
import re

text = 'Monika will go shopping. Mike likes Pizza. Monika hates me.'

names = ['Ruth', 'Mike', 'Monika']
rsplit = re.compile("|".join(sorted(names))).split

output = []
sentences = text.split(".")
for name in names:
    for sentence in sentences:
        if name in sentence:
            output.append([name, f"{rsplit(sentence)[-1]}."])

print(output)
```

This outputs:

```
[['Mike', ' likes Pizza.'], ['Monika', ' will go shopping.'], ['Monika', ' hates me.']]
```

Comment: Thanks for looking into this and pointing that out. I updated the example to make it more representative and implicitly answer questions as to the structure of `text`. Why do you *sort* when compiling the separator list? Because of multiple sentences, the point cannot be used as a separator, otherwise i would have dont it that way in the first place. Sorry for leaving that unclear in the original question text. if `sentences = text.split(rsplit)` would work, your answer would be applicable to my goal.

Comment: Well, in that case it's still very unclear on where to split and where to stop. If there are multiple subsequent sentences that are *somehow* connected to the name you want to split on, then you'd have to have a way to know when another sequence begins. From your examples this is not obvious.

Comment: I want to make the first cut when 1 element of `names` occurs and slice until a different (independent of order of elements in `names`) element of `names` occurs. `text` will never have the same unique `names` element occuring twice consecutively. I assume you cannot believe that my actual data is really structured like this, but it is. More precicely, the elements of `names` are much more unique than the example suggests. Again, I want to split every time 1 element of `names` occurs in `text`. Most of the time the output will have more lists as `names` has strings.

Answer (score 0):

This is without the re, unless you explicitly need to use it.. Works for the test case given..

```
text = 'Monika goes shopping. Then she rides bike. Mike likes Pizza. Monika hates me.'

names = ['Mike', 'Monika']

def sep(text, names):
    foo = []
    new_text = text.split(' ')
    for i in new_text:
        if i in names:
            foo.append(new_text[:new_text.index(i)])
            new_text = new_text[new_text.index(i):]
    foo.append(new_text)
    foo = foo[1:]

    new_foo = []
    for i in foo:
        first, rest = i[0], i[1:]
        rest = " ".join(rest)
        i = [first, rest]
        new_foo.append(i)
    print(new_foo)

sep(text, names)
```

Gives the output:

```
[['Monika', 'goes shopping. Then she rides bike.'], ['Mike', 'likes Pizza.'], ['Monika', 'hates me.']]
```

Should work for other cases too..